# Parse lua table in C (when table has no key)

Tags: c, lua

I can parse lua table from C when table has key/value pairs at all levels..

Example of lua tables

```
with_key={k1={v=1}, k2={v=2}}
without_key={{v=1}, {v=2}}
```

Parsing lua table (with_key) - as seen on https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_next
This is simplified code to illustrate what I'm doing

```
 /* table is in the stack at index 't' */
 lua_gettable(L, t);
 lua_pushnil(L);  /* first key */
 while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
    // Key is now at index -2 and value at -1
    // in sub-table and can find field I want
        lua_getfield(L, -1, "v");  // key hardcoded for simplicity
        int32_t isInteger;         // conversion OK
        int value = lua_tointegerx(L, -1, (int*)&isInteger);
        printf("Value %d", value);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    // Processing sub-table done
    /* removes 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration */
    lua_pop(L, 1);
 }
```

But the same code does not work if my table does not have keys (using without_key table).

Comment: The first line looks suspicious. Do you mean `lua_pushvalue`?

Comment: YES! That's it. I thought that lua_gettable is the way to push (select) item to parse, but I was wrong. Using lua_pushvalue fixes the code and now it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Use `lua_pushvalue` instead of `lua_gettable` in the first line of the code.